# Jquery counter doesnt work

Tags: jquery

I tried to create jquery counter

```
$.fn.counter = function (num) {
var self = $(this);
for (var i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
    setInterval(function () {
        self.html(i);
    }, 4000);
}
};

$('div').counter(100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rdy5B/14/

After the page loads I need to increase the values ​​in the block to a certain value, then counter stops. Why my code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the wrong usage of a closure variable and `setInterval()`

```
$.fn.counter = function (num) {
    var i = 1,
        self = $(this).html(i);
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        self.html(++i);
        if (i >= num) {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, 1000);
};

$('div').counter(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this,

```
var i=0;
setInterval(function () {
        i++;
    $("div").html(i);
    }, 4000);
```

You dont have to use for loop to increment the counter. Since setInterval calls repeatedly, you can put the logic for increment there itself.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G97bt/9/)

**Edit**

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
var i=0;
var num=4;
function myTimer()
{
    i++;
    $("div").html(i);
    if(i==num)
    {
        myStopFunction();
    }
}

function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G97bt/12/)

Comment: I need to stop counter after i === num.

Answer (score 1):

Your for is executed and one `setInterval` will be fired (because it wait 4 sec).

You can chenge your for and increment `i` inside the interval like:

```
$.fn.counter = function (num) {
    var self = $(this);
    var i=0;
    var int = setInterval(function () {        
        if (i > num) {
            clearInterval(int)
            return
        }
        i++;
        self.html(i);
    }, 4000);

};

$('div').counter(100);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5MjfT/